# EJB: embedded ejb helloworld

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I run this `jUnit` test:

```
public class HelloBeanITCase {
    @Test
    public void test1() throws NamingException {
        System.setProperty("org.jboss.as.embedded.ejb3.BARREN", "true");
        System.setProperty("org.jboss.as.ejb3.EMBEDDED", "true");
        System.setProperty("jboss.home", "/usr/local/share/jboss-eap-6.1");
        System.setProperty("jboss.home.dir", "/usr/local/share/jboss-eap-6.1");

        Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        properties.put(EJBContainer.PROVIDER,
                "org.jboss.as.embedded.ejb3.JBossStandaloneEJBContainerProvider");

        EJBContainer ec = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        Hello bean = (Hello) ctx.lookup("HelloBean/local");

        String now = new Date().toString();
        String actual = bean.sayHello(now);

        assertEquals("Hello " + now, actual);

        ec.close();
    }
}
```

But it fails with following exception:

```
17:52:55,092 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.classes".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.classes".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.classes:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Classpath:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:853) [jboss-modules-1.2.0.CR1.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1194) [jboss-modules-1.2.0.CR1.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1222) [jboss-modules-1.2.0.CR1.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:226) [jboss-modules-1.2.0.CR1.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more

17:52:55,298 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (pool-5-thread-1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "classes" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.classes\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.classes\".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.classes:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Classpath:main"}}
17:52:55,305 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment classes (runtime-name: classes) in 6ms
```

I want my `target/classes` to be deployed to Jboss. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of JBoss and do you package your classes somehow?

Comment: `jboss AS 7.2` currently I don't package. I tried with jar and got the same result

Comment: Have a look at which deployment descriptors JBoss requires to deploy an ejb jar. I normally deploy ear or war applications and thus don't know which exactly are needed but it might be ejb-jar.xml. There might also be a couple of module dependencies you need to define, either in MANIFEST.MF or jboss-deployment-structure.xml. Have a look here for a start: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+AS7.1 (AS7.1 and AS7.2 aren't different here)

Comment: Btw, I just realized you basically want to use JBoss during a test. Have a look at the Arquilian project which is meant to make exactly that as easy as possible.